VeeValidate handeSubmit Not returned values
I work with vee-validate validation for vue. I choose handleSubmit method:
<template>
  <div>
    <Form @submit="onSubmit" :validation-schema="schema">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">E-mail</label>
        <Field
          id="email"
          class="form-control"
          name="email"
          type="text"
          :validateOnInput="true"
        />
        <ErrorMessage class="invalid-feedback" name="email" />
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { Field, Form, ErrorMessage, useForm } from "vee-validate";
import * as yup from "yup";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Field,
    Form,
    ErrorMessage
  },
  setup() {
    const schema = yup.object({
      email: yup
        .string()
        .required("Email is required")
        .email("Email must be valid"),
    });

    const { handleSubmit } = useForm({
      validationSchema: schema,
    });

    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((values) => {
      console.log("Form submission triggered");
      console.log("Form values:", values);
      alert("Form submitted with values: " + JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    });

    return {
      schema,
      onSubmit,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.invalid-feedback {
  color: red;
}
</style>

validattion is working now But values not returned. how do fix this problem?
Demo: Here
